# org-mode : in a table, calculate a person's age based on their birthday

Tags: org-mode, org-table, formula

Let's say I have the following table:

```
| Name   | Age              | Date of Birth    | Income |
|--------+------------------+------------------+--------|
| Joe    |                  | <1984-02-20 Mon> |  84000 |
| Mark   |                  | <1974-04-15 Mon> | 120000 |
| Sophie |                  | <1970-08-28 Fri> | 150000 |
| Anna   |                  | <1988-02-29 Mon> | 160000 |
```

I want the second column to be the amount of years elapsed since the date in the third column.

I can't figure out how to do this with the TBLFM settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it something like the example below:

```
| Name   | Age          | Date of Birth    | Income |
|--------+--------------+------------------+--------|
| Joe    | 30 years old | <1984-02-20 Mon> |  84000 |
| Mark   | 40 years old | <1974-04-15 Mon> | 120000 |
| Sophie | 44 years old | <1970-08-28 Fri> | 150000 |
| Anna   | 26 years old | <1988-02-29 Mon> | 160000 |
#+TBLFM: $2=(now()-$3)/365;%d years old
```

Comment: Thank you! Where can I find out that there are such things as `now()` ?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Function-Index

Comment: @Trevoke Another way, which would typically work is to try `C-h f calc-now` - most Calc functions will have a corresponding Emacs Lisp function with the name prefixed with `calc-`.